# Java Spring Validation does not catch errors

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a little project.

Everything works fine except the Validation.

I have a Class calles Fighter, which has a name property that should'nt be NULL or Empty.
I did add everything for validation like my professor in his samples.

But if I add a Fighter with an empty name the error does not get catched and the new Fighter just get saved to the DB

Am I missing Something?

My Fighter Class

```java
@Entity
public class Fighter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "path")
    public String path;
}
```

The Add Function in the Controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/join")
    public String showFighterForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("fighter", new Fighter());
        return "add-fighter";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addfighter")
    public String addFighter(@Valid Fighter fighter, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-fighter";
        }
        fighter.setPath();
        fighterRepository.save(fighter);
        model.addAttribute("fighters", fighterRepository.findAll());
        return "character";
    }
```

Maybe someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Do you have an validator implementation? Just adding the `validation-api` depndency isn't enouhg, without something like `hibernate-validator` nothing is going to happen. An annotation is just meta-data you need something to process it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Recreate your db tables. You can do this manually or write this line in your application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

After recreating change the value on update

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try @NotEmpty annotation . it also checks the length of string. if it is greater than 0 or not.

Comment: I have tried @NotEmpty as well, it also is not working.